# Using RediSearch: Module Disabled in Open Source Redis

Tags: redis, redisearch, redislabs

I'm currently using Redis V4.09 on Ubuntu 18.04 and I downloaded RediSearch from https://redislabs.com/redis-enterprise-software/download-center/modules/

The module runs correctly with the Redis Server but when I try to use a command from RediSearch like FT.Create it responds with an error saying that the module is disabled in open-source redis.

I was told that RediSearch is free given its license, is it that the version on redis labs is an enterprise version? If so, where can I find the free version of RediSearch and its respective .so file.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OSS version of RediSearch doesn't currently provide pre-compiled .so files (although we're working on that). In the meantime, you can either a) download the source and compile (see the docs for instructions) or try to copy the .so from the official docker images (your mileage may vary).

The version you've downloaded from the RedisLabs website is, indeed, only compatible with the enterprise version.

Comment: When you say download the source and compile, are you referring to https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/Quick_Start/ as the docs? I tried building and running from source but I ran into a make error: ***no rule to make target 'build' do you know why that might be? I'm a windows user but I have ubuntu through WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)

Comment: Yes, that's what I was referring to. Feel free to open an issue at the RediSearch GitHub repository about WSL for assistance